# Autocomplete dropdown in Javascript need selected value

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I created a autocomplete dropdown for a table I have, but I need the get the selected value to use it to fill in the rest of the table.

```
function autocomp(){
    var dataList=document.getElementById("autopop");
    var input=document.getElementById("ajax");


           for(var i=0;i<Col1.length;++i){
               console.log("autocomplete function"); 
                //new <option>
                var option=document.createElement('option');
                //set value
                option.value=Col1[i];
                //add <option> to <datalist>
                dataList.appendChild(option);
                autocompaction=document.dropdown.ajax;

           }

           input.placeholder="Pick a material";           
};
```

Comment: are you trying to get the value from a select HTML element?

Comment: HTML code:<input type="text" id="ajax" list="autopop" >
                        <datalist id="autopop"></datalist>